# Mapping the MATLAB SP Toolbox to Mathematica

Tags: signal-processing, matlab

We have some work and people where I am doing signal processing using the signal processing toolbox in MATLAB and it comes up how to translate one or another of the large number of functions in that library to a corresponding Mathematica function or expression.

Is there a guide to how to map each of these functions in the MATLAB toolbox to a Mathematica expression?

Comment: You mean these functions? http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/functionlist.html

Comment: Somewhat related, though does not look at all close to complete at first glance: [Chapter 3: signal processing, Image processing, graphics, random numbers])http://12000.org/my_notes/mma_matlab_control/KERNEL/KEch3.htm#x124-1480003)